# Why does jaxrs multipart request throw IllegalStateException?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs

Why this code return this error?

Code:

```
    @Path("/site/resource/upload")
    @Local
    @Stateless
    public class TreeResourceResourcesUpload extends TreeBaseResources {

    @POST
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    @Consumes( MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA )
    public TreeNodeTO uploadResource(@Context HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, ServletException {
            for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
                System.out.println(part.getName());
            }
            return null;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC4016: Request.getParts is called without multipart configuration.  Either add a @MultipartConfig to the servlet, or a multipart-config element to web.xml
```

System:
Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and Sun JDK 7

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jersey as a Servlet, you can set multipart parameters in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <multipart-config>
            <location>/tmp</location>
            <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But I think this method is not in standard.
I was looking for an answer in the JAXRS specifications, and nothing.
So I supposed that is not possible access to .getPart in JAX-RS

Answer (score 1):

I seem to run into a similar problem. It looks like bug http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18444 which should be fixed in 3.1.2.2, but isn't?

Comment: Possible is late, but I answered with my temporal solution.